# How to play the TranslateTransition continuously with no stop

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Text that contains a String of 7 lines. I want to put this Text in a  panel width 500 and height 70 This text should smoothly move slowly from the bottom up and play again and again without stopping.
I did the following code.
But the text only once playing and floating movement is done with small jumps rather smoothly.
How I can do smooth motion and play it again and again without ever stop?

```
public class TextSh extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    String message =" Here is the text of seven lines";

Text textRef = TextBuilder.create()
    .layoutY(100)
    .textOrigin(VPos.TOP)
    .textAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
    .wrappingWidth(400)
    .text(message)
    /*.fill(Color.rgb(187, 195, 107))*/
    .fill(Color.OLIVE)
    .font(Font.font("SansSerif", FontWeight.BOLD, 18))
    .build();

TranslateTransition transTransition = TranslateTransitionBuilder.create()
    .duration(new Duration(75000))
    .node(textRef)
    .toY(-1640)
    .interpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR)
    .cycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE) 
     .autoReverse(true)    
     .build();       

      StackPane root = new StackPane();       
      root.getChildren().add(textRef);
      StackPane r = new StackPane();
      r.getChildren().add(root);        
      Scene scene = new Scene(r, 500, 70);        
      primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();     
      transTransition.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }



}
```

Comment: It does repeat indefinitely. (Well, I know for certain it repeats at least twice. You set the duration to 75 seconds, so it takes 2.5 minutes to go up and come back down. I didn't wait more than 5 minutes.) I don't see the "small jumps" you mention. As an aside, the builder classes are deprecated and should not be used; you should use regular constructor and set method calls instead.

Comment: Dear James_D thank you for taking the time to deal with my issue.
In each case how can be achieved for a text note to be presented into a clip width 500 and height 70, and drive bottom-up again from the bottom up without ever stopping. Finally this clip should be able to get into a panel of scene builder. Is there any other way to do this?